# Parsing DRF request body: TypeError the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman

When I try to send a JSON using a Django REST framework, I get this error:

> TypeError at /usermanagement/user/
>   the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

My post fuction:

```
def post(self,request):
    user=json.loads(request.body)
    m_user= user.get('m_name', None)
    m_email = user.get('m_email', None)
    m_age=user.get('m_age', None)
    m_status = user.get('u_status_id', None)

    user = M_User(m_name=m_name, m_email=m_email, m_age=m_age, u_status_id=m_status)
    user.save()
    if user.save:
        user=M_User.objects.filter(m_user=m_user)
        serializer = M_Userserializer(user,many=True)
        context = {
            'success': "true",
            'user': serializer.data
        }
    elif not user.save:
        context={
        'success':"false"
        }
    else:
        context={
        'success':"false"
        }

    return Response(context)
```

Comment: I don't think that the question is a duplicate of the proposed original question. This one applies to DRF and not the original one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DRF you can use [`request.data`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data) instead of `request.body` to get already parsed request:

```
user=request.data
```

In this case request should be `Request` istance instead standard django `HttpRequest`. To ensure this you need to use [`api_view`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) decorator:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view()
def post(self,request):
    user=request.data
```